# Why does this curl command to upload file to Tomcat work on Windows but not on Linux?

Tags: linux, tomcat, curl

This is my curl command to upload war file to tomcat:

curl -u admin:admin "http://server.com:8084/manager/text/deploy?path=/proxy&version=1.0.0-Snapshot" --upload-file "target/proxy##1.0.0-Snapshot.war"

It works on Windows , but not on Linux.

Even better:

On Windows executing this command takes pretty long. Of course , because there is really a file uploaded to the server

On Linux nevertheless the curl command is executed and ends after very short time, but
it returns
OK - Deployed application at context path [/proxy##1.0.0-Snapshot]

But actually it is not deployed!!

Comment: It's generally more fruitful to ignore the fact that it works on Windows and debug it entirely on Linux. There's no way to "convince" Linux to run it successfully by showing it that it works on Windows.

Comment: What could this message mean ? curl: (26) couldn't open file "target/proxy##1.0.0-Snapshot.war"   ??

Comment: It says it couldn't open the file. Regardless of what Windows does you should check if the file exists on Linux, and if it and you are in the right directory since it's a relative path.

Comment: Reason was Linux is case sensitive. Shame on me :)

Comment: Nice, I'm glad you got it running! You can consider deleting the question as a typo